# Access current page from inside a block, inside a StreamField

Tags: django, wagtail

Inside a block it would make sense to be able to access the calling page, ie its context, to be able to apply filter scopes to any data collections that I want to show in my block.

Here's a block template that I have:

```
<div class="fooblock__items">
  {% foo_tag calling_page=??? %}
</div>
```

As you can see, I want to send the calling page to the custom tag called `foo_tag` so I can use the calling page identifier in my tag logic:

```
@register.inclusion_tag('home/tags/foo.html', takes_context=True)
def foo_tag(context, calling_page=None):
  return {'foos': Foo.objects.filter(some_arg=calling_page.id)}
```

In my block template, how can I access the calling page model?

Comment: Found these sources of info, might help me, not sure yet...
https://github.com/torchbox/wagtail/issues/1743#issuecomment-143593450
https://github.com/torchbox/wagtail/issues/1743#issuecomment-225080709
https://gist.github.com/mgd020/d841f8016024707b11b490b82ec648f0

Comment: Just to check - you're talking about a block within a StreamField (with its own template assigned as part of the block definition), yes?

Comment: Yes, that's right. I should add that to the question, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't possible using the current method of rendering blocks through `{{ ... }}` tags, because Django doesn't pass on the context at that point. (Essentially, you're rendering a fixed HTML representation of the block, which knows nothing about the calling page.) The only current workaround is to avoid the use of block templates for anything that needs access to the outer context, and just loop over the stream values in the outer template instead.

There's a proposal in progress to introduce an `{% include_block %}` template tag, which would address this: https://github.com/torchbox/wagtail/issues/1743

Comment: Thanks @gasman for clearing that up. I did what you proposed, it looks something like this: https://gist.github.com/dwickstrom/1b8613b6e02d165c0a326731e53785dd

Comment: I was using `{{ ... }}` to include a block and it disrupted usage of the `{% csrf_token %}` tag deeper in nested stream fields. This helped me to see I needed `{% include_block ... %}` all the way down.